# Circulation in network flow

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

I am reading Algorithms book written by Robert Sedwick.

> Note: "s" is source and "t" is tank.
>
> Augument any flow network with an edge from "t" to "s" with flow and
>   capacity equal to the network's value, and know that inflow is equal
>   to outflow for any set of nodes in the augumented network. Such a flow
>   is called a circulation, and this construction demonstrates  that the
>   maxflow problem reduces to the problem of finding a circulation that
>   maximizes the flow along a given edge.
>
> Given a set of cycles and a flow value for each cycle, it is easy to
>   compute the corresponding circulation by following through each cycle
>   and adding the indicated flow to each edge. The converse property is
>   more surprising; We can find a set of cycles (with a flow value for
>   each) that is equivalent to any given circulation.
>
> Flow decomposition theorm: Any circulation can be represented as flow
>   along a set of atmost E directed cycles.

My questions on above explanation

1. Request to explain with example what does author mean and how we can reduce "maxflow problem reduces to the problem of finding a circulation
   that maximizes the flow along a given edge. "?
2. Can any one explain with simple example following paragraph.

> "Given a set of cycles and a flow value for each cycle, it is easy to
>   compute the corresponding circulation by following through each cycle
>   and adding the indicated flow to each edge. The converse property is
>   more surprising; We can find a set of cycles (with a flow value for
>   each) that is equivalent to any given circulation."

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If you have a maxflow problem with source s and sink t, you can convert this problem into a maximum circulation problem by just adding an edge t->s. The original maximum flow from s to t is now converted into a maximum circulation s--->t->s.
2. If you have a list of cycles (closed paths in your graph) and every cycle is associated with a flow N, you can go through all the cycles and add the flow values N to those edges the cycles go through. In this fashion, every edge in your graph will have a flow value calculated for it, and this is the total circulation in your graph. Conversely, the theorem says that whenever you have a circulation in the total graph, it can be decomposed into cycles. Here is an example of a maximum circulation, on every edge the notation a(b) means that the flow is a and edge maximum capacity is b:

   ```
     3(3)     2(2)
   a ----> b -----> c 
   ^       |1(1)    |
   |3(3)   V        V 2(4)
   d<------e<-------f
      3(4)     2(3)
   ```

The corresponding cycles are: a-b-e-d-a with flow value 1, and a-b-c-f-e-d with flow value 2. Those two cycles together define the maximum circulation as shown above.