# Guarantee about edge not being part of a minimum spanning tree

Tags: algorithm, graph, minimum-spanning-tree

I was solving exercises from the Algorithm Design book by Kleinberg and Tardos and came across this not-so-easy (to me) problem on finding a guarantee that an edge will never belong to the MST of a graph. The question goes like this:

You are given a graph G = (V, E) with cost c_e on each edge e. Given error parameters epsilon and k (both > 0), you would like to ascertain whether the following property (*) holds for a particular edge e' = (u, v) in polynomial time.

(*) Even if the cost of each edge were to be changed by at most epsilon (either increased or decreased), and the costs of k edges other than e' were further changed to some arbitrary different values, the edge e' would still not belong to any MST of G.

I know  the cut property for MST's but cannot see how that can be applied to this problem. Thanks for your ideas in advance!

Comment: Well, a sufficient (but possibly unnecessarily strong) condition for surviving k changed edges would be that e is the heaviest edge in k+1 or more cycles that are pairwise edge-disjoint (except for edge e itself).  Then changing any k edges could at most render e non-heaviest in k of these cycles, leaving at least 1 cycle in which it remains the heaviest and so can never appear in any MST.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: OK, I see a glimmer of a solution. The answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10545472/circulation-in-network-flow) question shows how you can model cycle-finding as a network circulation problem.
Suppose you set capacities of all edges to 1, one end of e' as source and other as sink, and see if you get a circulation of value k+1.
If you do get that circulation that means e' is part of k+1 edge-disjoint cycles (except for e' itself). How do you ensure it is the _most expensive_ though?

Comment: That sounds like a workable approach.  To make sure e is the heaviest edge in each of these cycles, just (temporarily) delete any edges heavier than it before performing your network flow calculation! :)

Comment: @j_random_hacker: Awesome! I'll add that as an answer now. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, but remember to also address the epsilon part!  Though I think this is the easier condition to handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually reached an answer thanks to j_random_hacker's comments.

The answer basically uses the cycle properties of an MST - if an edge is the most expensive edge in a cycle in G, it cannot belong to any MST of G.

The provision for changing the costs of k edges to *arbitrary* values implies that we must show that e' is the most expensive edge in at least k+1 cycles which are all edge-disjoint except for e' itself. This way, even if the arbitrary change of k edges causes e' to not be the most expensive in k cycles, it will still be the most expensive in the last cycle.

Given a graph G, edge e' and parameters k and epsilon (both > 0):

1. Temporarily delete all edges in G more expensive than e' (this ensures that e' is the most expensive in whichever cycles we find)
2. Now, set one end of e' to be a source (s) and the other end to be a sink (t). Set capacities of all edges to be 1. Flow integrality ensures that since all capacities are integers, we will get an integral flow.
3. See if you get a flow of value at least k+1. If yes, flow decomposition will give you as many edge-disjoint paths from s to t as the value of flow. Convert all these paths to cycles by adding e' to them - this way you have k+1 (or more) cycles in which e' is the most expensive edge and which are all edge-disjoint except for e'. You can now safely say that property (*) holds for e'.

I have a way to deal with epsilon if it is an integer. In step 1, delete all edges that are more expensive than cost(e) + 2*epsilon.

Comment: We can't yet claim that e' *must* be the most expensive edge in k+1 cycles. Suppose we have 2k+1 cycles, each of which shares an edge with 2 other cycles in the set and no edges with any other cycle in the set (e.g. imagine cycle c[i] shares an edge with c[i-1] and a different edge with c[i+1], "wrapping" at 0 and k). Then choosing k edges to downweight can "kill" at most 2k cycles, meaning there is still some cycle in which e is heaviest even though there aren't k+1 pairwise-disjoint cycles containing it! Perhaps it can be shown that this situation is impossible, but we haven't done so yet.

Comment: I've edited the answer a bit. I think the point here is to have _only_ e' common to _all_ those cycles. If there are more than k+1 such cycles, it doesn't hurt our case.

Comment: There are 2 separate questions: (1) Is the condition *sufficient*? (I.e. is the condition strong enough to guarantee that e' will never appear in an MST even after the permitted modifications?)  The answer to this is definitely "yes".  Question (2) is: Is the condition *necessary*?  (I.e. if we know that an edge e' will never appear in an MST even after the permitted modifications, can we know for certain that it must obey the condition?) ...

Comment: ... It's the answer to (2) that's not clear, but the way you have phrased part of your answer (specifically "... implies that we must show that e' is the most expensive edge in at least k+1 cycles") claims (or can be interpreted as claiming) that the answer to (2) is also "yes".  What I tried to sketch in my first comment was a potential counterexample, i.e. an instance in which there is an edge e' that will never appear in an MST even after the permitted modifications, but which nevertheless does not obey the k+1 edge-disjoint cycles condition.